# Segment not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

We have two CustomCell.We need changed based on Segment click 
We tried like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(_Segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
        static NSString * receivedAlertsIdentifier = @"DosageReport";
        DR = (DosageReport *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:receivedAlertsIdentifier];
        if (DR == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DosageReport" owner:self options:nil];
            DR = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
       }
        DR.DosageTaken.text=[DosageTakenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       //etc
    }
    else if (_Segment.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
        {
            static NSString * receivedAlertsIdentifier = @"DispenserReport";
            DPR = (DispenserReport *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:receivedAlertsIdentifier];
            if (DPR == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DispenserReport" owner:self options:nil];
                DR = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
                //[cell addSubview:cell.GetImageShow];
            }
            DPR.Status.text=[Status objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            DPR.Date.text=[DispenserArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [DPR.Status setTintColor:kColourSwitchTint];
        //ect
            return DPR;
         }

    return DPR;
}
```

we have tried like this but it's show always  only one view . Please guide to us.  what wrong in our code
 Segment click

```
- (IBAction)ChangedSegu:(id)sender {
         NSLog(@"Selectitmes");
        if(_Segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        {
            DR.hidden =NO;
            DPR.hidden = YES;

        }
        else if (_Segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
        {
            DR.hidden=YES;
            DPR.hidden = NO;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

call `[self.tableView reloadData];` (Replace "tableView" to whatever is your tableView called) at the end of segment change.

You can do it in a very simple way. Declare a `BOOL` that will be used to tell tableview which cell to show. On segment change set the BOOL and call `[self.tableView reloadData];` (Replace "tableView" to whatever is your tableView called).

On - `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, check for the `BOOL` and set your appropriate cell.